# CSS responsive background

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to learn on making responsive website and right now I come up with this problem where when I shrink the website horizontally to a width just right before the edge of the screen touches one of the element, the background also shrinks , leaving a white space.

I am using this html

```
        <div className="first-layer">
            <div className="background-wrapper">
                <Navbar></Navbar>
                {/* <Overview></Overview> */}
            </div>
        </div>
```

with this as navbar

```
        <div className="navbar-container">
            <div className="logo">Razark</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="TierList">Tier List</a></li>
                <li><a href="About">Blog</a></li> 
                <li><a href="About">About</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and this css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
.background-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, 
        rgba(41, 0, 37, 0.5),
        rgba(47, 2, 43, 0.5),
        rgba(54, 0, 49, 0.5),
        rgba(62, 2, 56, 0.5),
        rgba(69, 2, 62, 0.5),
        rgba(71, 1, 67, 0.5),
        rgba(74, 1, 71, 0.5),
        rgba(76, 0, 76, 0.5),
        rgba(73, 0, 80, 0.5),
        rgba(69, 0, 84, 0.5),
        rgba(64, 0, 88, 0.5),
        rgba(58, 1, 92, 0.5)
    );
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.navbar-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
}
.navbar-container ul{
        /* border: 3px solid red; */
    background-color: rgba(41, 0, 37, 0.3);
    border-radius:999px ;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-container ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar-container ul li a {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 18px;

    color: white;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

.navbar-container ul li a:hover{
    color: #0affc2;
}
.logo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 48px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.Overview{
    /* column-gap: 2rem;
    column-count: 2; */
}

.left-overview{
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
}
.right-overview{
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

How do i make the background always shrink no matter the elements and size of the page

Comment: can you provide some images of white space you talking about

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the space created by the scroll bar? I don't get any other space.

Answer (score 0):

If you can explain a bit more about your problem. I put the code in an online compiler and the main responsive issue is from the navigation overflow which creates a scrollbar on the x-axis because it extends past the width of the div with the background, so it is more than 100%. If that's not your goal, handling the overflow will fix the whitespace.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have written the required media queries to take care of the responsiveness and display as you expected. This is basically writing the units in viewport width so that those elements can shrink with the screen size. Below are the changes I have made:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 630px){
    .navbar-container ul li a {
        font-size: 2.5vw;               
        padding: 0 3.5vw 0 3.5vw;                  
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px){
    .logo{                                                
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
.background-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, 
        rgba(41, 0, 37, 0.5),
        rgba(47, 2, 43, 0.5),
        rgba(54, 0, 49, 0.5),
        rgba(62, 2, 56, 0.5),
        rgba(69, 2, 62, 0.5),
        rgba(71, 1, 67, 0.5),
        rgba(74, 1, 71, 0.5),
        rgba(76, 0, 76, 0.5),
        rgba(73, 0, 80, 0.5),
        rgba(69, 0, 84, 0.5),
        rgba(64, 0, 88, 0.5),
        rgba(58, 1, 92, 0.5)
    );
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.navbar-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
}
.navbar-container ul{
        /* border: 3px solid red; */
    background-color: rgba(41, 0, 37, 0.3);
    border-radius:999px ;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-container ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar-container ul li a {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 18px;

    color: white;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px){
    .navbar-container ul li a {
        font-size: 2.5vw;               
        padding: 0 3.5vw 0 3.5vw;                  
    }
}

.navbar-container ul li a:hover{
    color: #0affc2;
}
.logo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 48px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 36px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px){
    .logo{                                                
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
}

.Overview{
    /* column-gap: 2rem;
    column-count: 2; */
}

.left-overview{
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
}
.right-overview{
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-layer">
    <div class="background-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <div class="logo">Razark</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="TierList">Tier List</a></li>
                <li><a href="About">Blog</a></li> 
                <li><a href="About">About</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```